# How to route/link each user to their own data?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have stored in `Firebase Firestore` a bunch of users.

[image]

Then I created a `Vue` component where a picture is with a `router-link` to a user profile if I click on that picture I would want to go to the users profile site from the user which posted the picture.

```
<router-link v-bind:to="{ name: 'view-post', params:{ userId:post.userId}}">
  <v-img :src="post.image" alt="pic"></v-img>
</router-link>
```

This is my code right now, yes very empty I know and it is a `Vue` component

```
   <template>
     <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-content>


      </v-content>
     </v-layout>
   </template>

  <script>
   import { mapState } from 'vuex'
   const fb = require('../firebaseConfig.js')

   export default {
    name: 'view-employee',
    data: () => ({

    }),
    computed: {
     ...mapState(['userProfile', 'currentUser', 'posts'])
    },
    methods: {

    }
  }
 </script>
```

Inside the computed property `...mapState` are stored the posts, users and the currentUser from `firestore`

Router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import World from './views/World.vue'
import Login from '@/components/Login'
import ViewEmployee from '@/components/ViewEmployee'

 Vue.use(Router)

   const router = new Router({
     mode: 'history',
     routes: [
      {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'login',
        component: Login,
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: false
        }
      },
      {
       path: '/world',
       name: 'world',
       component: World,
       meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
       }
      },
      {
       path: '/post/:userId',
       name: 'view-post',
       props: true,
       component: ViewEmployee,
       meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
       }
     }
   ]
 })


  export default router
```

Comment: Your question is really broad... There are many different ways to achieve your goals. I suggest you have a look at this tutorial https://savvyapps.com/blog/definitive-guide-building-web-app-vuejs-firebase

Comment: I know this tutorial I had read it, but no help from there

Comment: I want to link each user which I stored in firestore to their own profile so that the currentUser see his profile and can click on links to go to another profile

Comment: Another example is that if the currentUser click on a picture and this picture has a route to the users profile site which had have post the picture. How can I display then the data for the one user who posted the picture?

Comment: The best we can do with what you've shown is make suggestions that may not be relevant to what you've don so far.  For example, you can narrow down the area you are having trouble by showing where in your code are you connecting to firebase, detailing any errors you are discovering in your network traffic or console...

Comment: You have not posted any of the code for your vue-router configuration, which would seem to be relevant to your question. Are you missing that part?

Comment: oh yes I forgot sorry, I have added the part now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code of your Vue router you could do as follows:

1/ In your view-post component (that you reach through `/post/:userId`) grab the value of the `userId` with `this.$route.params.userId`.

2/ Fetch the data from Firestore based on the value of `userId`, in the `created` lifecycle hook.

3/ Display the data in your DOM.

You will find in the Vue router documentation a page that explains this mechanism into detail, either by fetching the data After Navigation or by fetching it before Navigation: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html

If we adapt the Fetching After Navigation example we get the following code for displaying, for example, the `userName`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="loading" v-if="loading">
      Loading...
    </div>

    <div v-if="error" class="error">
      {{ error }}
    </div>

    <div v-if="userName" class="content">
      <h2>{{ userName }}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      loading: false,
      userName: null,
      error: null
    }
  },
  created () {
    // fetch the data when the view is created and the data is
    // already being observed
    this.fetchData();
  },
  watch: {
    // call again the method if the route changes
    '$route': 'fetchData';
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData () {
      var vm = this;
      vm.error = vm.post = null;
      vm .loading = true;

      //We make the assumption that there is a Collection userProfiles
      //with documents with ids equal to the userIds
      fb.collection("userProfiles").doc(this.$route.params.userId).get()
      .then(function(doc) {
         if (doc.exists) {
           vm.loading = false;
           vm.userName = doc.data().userName;
         } else {
           vm.error = "No such document!";
         }
       })
       .catch(function(error) {
           vm.error = "Error getting document:" + error;
       });

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great I will test it

Comment: Note that there was a typo in the line `this.userName = doc.data().userName;`. I've corrected it!

Comment: I got an error: Cannot set property 'error' of undefined

Comment: Where??? You have to give more details on which line you get this error. Look at the browser console. Also, you may install this Chrome/Firefox browser extension for debugging Vue.js applications https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools

Comment: overall where this.error is called, I remove every this.error 
except one and I get also the error there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177629/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-lukas).

Comment: so the error comes by the .catch function and the else {...}